# Mac Appstore : URL to open the list of the apps of one developer in Mac Appstore from an OSX app?

Tags: macos, url, app-store

I want to open the Mac Appstore from my OSX app and to give as result the list of my OSX apps.

On iOS, the link to the iOS appstore is the following one :

http://itunes.apple.com/apps/DEVELOPER_NAME

The question is : what is the similar link to the Mac Appstore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the app store, open the page for an app by that developer, and right click on the "More Apps by ..." link, you can copy it and paste it wherever you want.

Example: The link for Apple is http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/apple/id284417353?mt=12.

[image]

Comment: Note: if you replace the `http` in the URL with `macappstore` then the URL open will open up the Mac App Store directly instead of through your default web-browser.